# Firs time capistrano deploy failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

My first deploy to a new server seem to be failing with the following error message:

```
failed: "sh -c 'cat /var/www/my_project/production/current/REVISION'" on 192.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

This is not my first capistrano deploy and dont remember encountering anything like this before... any pointers to fix this will he really appreciated.

Here is more from the deployment log

```
 [192.xxx.xxx.xxx] executing command
    command finished in 1202ms
    triggering after callbacks for `deploy:finalize_update'
  * 2013-09-09 18:54:37 executing `postgresql:symlink'
  * executing "ln -nfs /var/www/my_application/production/shared/config/database.yml /var/www/my_application/production/releases/20130909132425/config/database.yml"
    servers: ["192.xxx.xxx.xxx"]
    [192.xxx.xxx.xxx] executing command
    command finished in 1042ms
    triggering after callbacks for `deploy:update_code'
  * 2013-09-09 18:54:38 executing `deploy:assets:precompile'
  * executing "cat /var/www/my_application/production/current/REVISION"
    servers: ["192.xxx.xxx.xxx"]
    [192.xxx.xxx.xxx] executing command
    command finished in 1039ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /var/www/my_application/production/releases/20130909132425; true"
    servers: ["192.xxx.xxx.xxx"]
    [192.xxx.xxx.xxx] executing command
    command finished in 1103ms
failed: "sh -c 'cat /var/www/my_application/production/current/REVISION'" on 192.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

The `cap deploy:check` is running successfully with

"You appear to have all necessary dependencies installed"

Comment: I sometime have permission problems with some capistrano new install. Can you ensure all files in your deploy path are readable and writable by your user ?

Comment: @OlivierElMekki, thanks for replying I, infact ran into the issue posted over here: 
https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/issues/224
and
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10907242/capistrano-error-current-no-such-file-or-directory/13014755

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ran into the issue posted over here:

https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/issues/224 and

[capistrano error: ...../current: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10907242/capistrano-error-current-no-such-file-or-directory/13014755)

Had to comment the `deploy/assets` line for the first deploy.

Answer (score 0):

How are you trying to deploy?
First deployment to servers should be done with deploy:cold

```
cap deploy:cold
```